# Is there a way to put the main.py file into a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have been working on an assignment with several text files, but an getting the file not found error. I was told to put all the text files into a folder as well as the main program. How can I put the main.py file into a folder with the rest of the files?

Code:

```
def main():
    process_file("good_data.txt")
    process_file("bad_data.txt")
    process_file("empty_file.txt")
    process_file("does_not_exist.txt")

def process_file(param_str_file_name):

  #Variables
  num_rec = 0
  total = 0
  average = 0

  try:
      file_name = open('param_str_file_name', 'r')

      print("Processing file", file_name)

      variable = file_name.readline()

      while variable != "":
        file_name_int = int(file_name)
        num_rec = num_rec + 1

        variable = file_name.readline()

        total += file_name_int
        average = total / num_rec

      file_name.close()

      print("\tRecord count = ", num_rec)
      print("\tTotal        = ", total)
      print("\tAverage      = " , f"{average:.2f}", "\n")

  except EOFError:
      print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " is empty. Cannot calculate average\n")

  except FileNotFoundError:
      print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " File not found\n")

  except ValueError:
      print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, "contains non-numeric data\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: `file_name = open('param_str_file_name', 'r')` this should be `file_name = open(param_str_file_name, 'r')`

Comment: How are you running the python program? Is it on the command line? Programs have a Current Working Directory (cwd) that is used when accessing a relative file name. If you `open("foo.txt")`, it is assumed to be in the CWD. If you are running on the command line, the directory you are in when you run the script is that directory. Use the correct variable name as pointed out and run from the directory containing the files and the open will work.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem #1

This may have nothing to do with your code, but just move your `main.py` file into the same folder as your text files.

If you want to keep your text files in a different directory however, try using this code:

```py
import os 

os.chdir('/path/to/the/folder')
```

This will change where your program looks. This is called change directory (also known as `cd` or `chdir`).

## Problem #2

You use `"param_str_file_name"` as a string instead of using the argument in the

```py
file_name = open('param_str_file_name', 'r')
```

line.

Comment: That's not quite it. If the file name isn't absolute, its relative to the current working directory, which doesn't have to be the same directory as the .py file.

Answer (score -1):

With most text editors, you can simply create a file in a folder, or you could drag a code file into a folder.